# How to remove rows from a specific column for preparing training and test set for SVR

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

A dataset has more than `2500 rows` and `22 columns` including the `age column`. I have completed all of the processes for SVR. It going on. But I am still having to face an error. That is `raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape)), ValueError: bad input shape (977, 57)`. My input is `SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)`. How can I resolve this problem?

```
from sklearn.model_selection 
import train_test_split 
from sklearn.svm import SVR 

X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], dataset.loc[:1000] 
X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001] 
train_X, train_y = X_train.drop(columns=['age']), y_train.pop('age')
test_X, test_y = X_test.drop(columns=['age']), y_test.pop('age')

raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (977, 57)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to drop the first `x` rows of a given column, use[DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```py
df = df.drop(range(end))
```

Where `end` is the number of rows you want to remove from the beginning of the dataset.

*Note: you cannot drop elements from a single column only. You must either drop all rows or replace the removed values with NaN or some other replacement value*

## Update

After further clarification by OP, the end result is to remove the `age`column from the `X_*` dataframes, and store the `age` column in its own dataframe `*_y`

```py
from sklearn.model_selection 
import train_test_split 
from sklearn.svm import SVR 

X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], dataset.loc[:1000] 
X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001] 
train_X, train_y = X_train.drop(columns=['age']), y_train.pop('age')
test_X, test_y = X_test.drop(columns=['age']), y_test.pop('age')
```

Should give you the desired end result.

Comment: As you may see my X_train, y_train have the same sizes. Actually, they are identical because I generate them with this line of code 
`X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], dataset.loc[:1000]`

X_train should contain only the features (i.e. it should not contain the target values, which is the ` "age" column`) and y_train should contain only one column of data (target values) which is ` "age" column` for this problem. 

How may I solve this problem?

Comment: ```train_X, train_y = X_train.drop(columns=['age']), y_train.pop('age'); 
test_X, test_y = X_test.drop(columns=['age']), y_test.pop('age')
```

Should give you the desired end result.

Comment: Should I have to remove below lines:

`X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001]; 
train_X, train_y = dataset.drop(columns=['age']), y_test['age'];
test_X, test_y = dataset.drop(columns=['age']), X_test['age'] `

Comment: You would not need to change this line `X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001]` because it creates the `X_*` and `y_*` datasets needed to create the desired end result. I have updated my answer to include the full code you will need.

Comment: But here X_train and y_train still have the same sizes.

I want the result such as, where `X_train` should contain only the features i.e. it should not contain the target values, which is the age column. Because the age column is my `target column`. In another word, it should contain the other column of my datasets. On the other hand, `y_train` should contain only `one column` of data target values which is `age column`

Comment: The code provided in my answer does *exactly* what you're asking. Both datasets with have the same `len()` value, because they have the same number of rows. `train_X` with have 1000 rows and some number of columns, while `train_y` will have 1000 rows and 1 column.

Comment: is this the correct solution. May I go ahead with this result? or I have to change anything else?
Should I have to change anything from below the line :

`X_test, y_test    = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001]`

Comment: Given your stated requirements, you shouldn't need to change anything more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very kind of You

Comment: Happy to help -- in the future, it can be extrememly helpful to give an example of what your data looks like to begin with, and what you want it to look like at the end. Good luck!

Comment: Dear Mentor, I am facing an error yet. I have updated my post

Comment: You should start a new question, instead of editing a question you've already accepted an answer to. I believe you can ping me @Bobs-Burgers in your new question, so I see it right away

Comment: I do not have a limit to asking any questions. For this reason, I made an answer. Please may check it

Comment: please may click this link. This is my new post from another account.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900518/how-to-resolve-raise-valueerrorbad-input-shape-0-formatshape-valueerror

Comment: Please may help me to solve this probelm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996792/how-to-generate-x-train-by-for-loop-at-every-iteration-of-the-loop