# How to resolve raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape)); ValueError: bad input shape (977, 57)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regsvr32

A dataset has more than `2500 rows` and `22 columns` including the age column. I have completed all of the processes for SVR. It going on. But I am still having to face an error. That is `raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape)), ValueError: bad input shape (977, 57)`. My input is `SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)`. How can I resolve this problem?

```
from sklearn.model_selection 
import train_test_split 
from sklearn.svm import SVR 

X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], dataset.loc[:1000] 
X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[1001], dataset.loc[1001] 
train_X, train_y = X_train.drop(columns=['age']), y_train.pop('age')
test_X, test_y = X_test.drop(columns=['age']), y_test.pop('age')

SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Ouputs :

```
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (977, 57)
```

Comment: @Bobs-Burgers  please may check this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in `train_X, train_y` to your `.fit` function. You're currently passing in `X_train` which is the dataset *before* you remove the `age` column.

This is what it should be

```py
SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(train_x, train_y)
```